# Black screen only on restart

Tags: windows, boot

I have an Acer Aspire S3 and using Windows 8.1. Every time when I restart my laptop I get a black screen when it's booting up. But the weird thing is, it only happens when I restart. In order to fix this I just have to turn-off the power and then turn it on again.

Comment: Can you check in the windows event viewer if there is anything peculiar before the winlogon event? I suspect it must be some system process, like (and not exactly) checkdisk going on, because, as you say, after a few minutes, it goes off... But, still, it is weird that it happens only on restart.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied the update relating to this problem as detailed in [KB 2756559](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2756559) by Microsoft? More information in this blog post, http://www.mytechguide.org/13149/windows-black-screen-with-cursor-fix/

If this doesn't solve your problem, it is likely a driver issue or a third party program. Some things you could try:

- Set a restore point
- Roll back recent hardware drivers for graphics and wifi cards
- Uninstall third party programs you installed recently

Comment: No my problem doesn't happen after it's booted up into windows. My problem happens while booting up.

Answer (score 0):

Disable "fast start-up" in Windows 8.1 and see if this solves problem.

System Settings -> Power Options -> Turn on fast start-up -> disable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's not working. I also found out something else. When I wait like 3 or more minutes the Black screen goes away and it boots normally.